# Reading last element of div instead of first element in accessibility through arrow keys

Tags: javascript, html

Reading - Some text on page load then No instead of Yes

```html
<div>
    <div role="alert" aria-live="assertive"> Some text on page load</div>
    <div>
        <button> Yes</button>
        <button> No</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't simply switch both button  ? Place "No" before "Yes"

Comment: plus 1 to that, just switch the DOM order and that will fix it.

Comment: Shall I start a bounty for this? xD

Comment: @himanshi could you explain **why** you can't switch the DOM order please. There might be a really good reason but without knowing it you are going to get a load of answers that might make this worse for you. What is the reason for wanting to change the order and why can't you change the DOM? Is this meant to be like a confirm dialog you are creating with default to No? Or are you creating a RTL theme or something like that? What is the purpose of the div being `assertive` if it is on page load? sorry lots of questions but by knowing your use case and constraints it makes it easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply switch the order of the elements as shown below

```html
<div>
<div role="alert" aria-live="assertive"> Some text on page load</div>
<div>
<button> No</button>
<button> Yes</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This will change the UI structure

Comment: So what's the issue on changing it, that's the simplest way isn't instead of writing again more logic on it

Answer (score 0):

There's no other solution but swapping the two buttons, as suggested by DILEEP THOMAS.

Document/browse/virtual cursors of screen reader always read content in the order of the accessibility tree, which is more or less the same as the DOM tree.
There is no way to change the reading order. If you want a content to be read in a particular order, then it must appear in that order in the tree. Period.

If it doesn't appear **visually** in the right order, then it's your responsability to fix your CSS to make it look like what you want.
However, think twice before doing that: why screen reader users should read "no" and then "yes", while normal users should first see "yes" before "no" ?

Very often, it's a signal of bad design, and bad design for all users (whether you have sight or not).

Note also that if you use CSS to visually swap the buttons,

- Depending on the exact code used, some screen readers will take your CSS into account, while other won't. Most won't, but you can never be 100% sure of that.
- Partially sighted and keyboard-only users will still ahve a problem, because the tab order is going to be in an unexpected/illogical order, i.e. people in western culture expect tab order to run top to bottom and left to right, while your CSS code will necessarily imply the opposite.
  For that last point, using other values than 0 and -1 for tabindex is a very bad idea. The details on why have already been covered at many places on the web.

Answer (score 0):

## You can't.

Your post is tagged with `nvda` and `accessibility` tags, then accessibility is a concern for you.

[WCAG guideline 2.4.3](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/navigation-mechanisms-focus-order.html) states that

> If a Web page can be navigated sequentially and the navigation sequences affect meaning or operation, focusable components receive focus in an order that preserves meaning and operability.

You have to create a [logical tab order](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20161007/H4) which means that if your language reading order is `ltr` (left-to-right). Elements on the left should be focused before elements on the right.

For `rtl` (right-to-left) languages,you have to place the elements in the same order as they appear in the DOM from top to bottom and right to left, and to define the `dir="rtl"` attribute.

Answer (score -1):

if Buttons would be navigated via `tab` instead of arrow, you can use `tabindex` to order them accordingly.

```html
<div>
<div role="alert" aria-live="assertive"> Some text on page load</div>
<div>
<button tabindex="2"> Yes</button>
<button tabindex="1"> No</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of this, you can simply change the order. I think this creates additional logic and the UI looks will be in the same

Comment: I agree, I'm just giving an alternate, assuming the OP has some restriction to keep the order unchanged.

Comment: Cool, no issues :)

Comment: need to do with arrow keys

Comment: @himanshi if arrow keys are working to navigate among buttons there must be some scripting to achieve that, as i don't think browsers allpw that by default. Please share the scripts for it, we can suggest modifications over it.

Comment: Whoever downvoted, an explanation would be greatly appreciated.